# Android setOnClickListener(this) Error

Tags: java, android

I have created a button in my Android application & I tried to set onclick listner to run  onClick method like follows

```
...
Button btn_ok;
    btn_ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn_ok.setOnClickListener(this);


}
public void onClick() {
     EditText uN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
     uN.setText("Clicked!");
    }
```

But Eclipse shows an error & says that "setOnClickListener" need to Cast Argument. After casting it is like this

```
btn_ok.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

Then when I'm running the program Emulator says that "Program has stopped unexpectedly"...
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Most likely you are importing/implementing the wrong `onClickListener` make sure it is the one for `View` and not the one for `DialogInterface`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that your class implements View.OnClickListener. You can`t just add onClick method, you must implement interface

Answer (score 5):

The signature of your `onClick` method is wrong, which leads me to believe you're not actually implementing the interface [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

The signature should be:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    //your implementation, v is your button that was clicked
}
```

Note that the View that was clicked is passed in as an argument, so there's no need to call `findViewById` from inside your `onClick` method.

Answer (score 5):

implement the onClickListener from your activity and override the method:

```
@override

public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch(v.getId()){
      case R.id.button1:
         EditText uN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText04);
         uN.setText("Clicked!");
         break;
       case default:
         break;
 }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`setOnClickListener` take an `OnClickListener` instance as parameter and `OnClickListener` is an interface which content an `onClick()` method and you are passing here setOnClickListener(this); current context. so you have two option either implements `OnClickListener` in your activity and second use this way :

```
  this.btn_ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //do your work here
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are implementing the interface View.OnClickListener and also pass View to onClick method